# When i run this SELECT = [Error] Execution (27: 14): ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle

When i run this SQL I get this message - [Error] Execution (ORA-01722: invalid number.

```
    SELECT 
             D.UNIT_CODE,
             CASE 
             
                  WHEN D.CAPITOL = 416 THEN 'CAP1'
                  WHEN D.CAPITOL = 417 THEN 'CAP2'
                  WHEN D.CAPITOL = 418 THEN 'Informativ'
                  WHEN D.CAPITOL = 419 THEN 'Cap. SR'
             END 
              AS CAPITOL,
             D.RIND,   
             SUM(D.COL1) AS COL1,
             SUM(D.COL2) AS COL2,
             SUM(D.COL3) AS COL3,
             SUM(D.COL4) AS COL4,
             SUM(D.COL5) AS COL5,
             SUM(D.COL6) AS COL6,
             SUM(D.COL7) AS COL7,
             SUM(D.COL8) AS COL8,
             SUM(D.COL9) AS COL9,
             SUM(D.COL10) AS COL10,
             SUM(D.COL11) AS COL11,
             SUM(D.COL12) AS COL12,
             SUM(D.COL13) AS COL13,
             SUM(D.COL14) AS COL14,
             SUM(D.COL15) AS COL15,
             SUM(D.COL16) AS COL16,
             SUM(D.COL17) AS COL17,
             SUM(D.COL18) AS COL18,
             SUM(D.COL19) AS COL19
           
            
            
    FROM
      VW_DATA_ALL_GC  D
      
      
      
    WHERE
      (D.PERIOADA IN (:pPERIOADA))  AND   
      (D.FORM =:pFORM) AND
      (D.FORM_VERS =:pFORM_VERS) AND 
      (:pID_MDTABLE =:pID_MDTABLE) AND 
      (D.CUATM_FULL LIKE '%'||:pCOD_CUATM||';%') AND
      D.FORM IN (58)  AND
      D.CAPITOL IN (419,416,417,418)
      
      
      GROUP BY 
       D.UNIT_CODE,
       D.CAPITOL,
       D.RIND  
      
        ORDER BY 
       D.CAPITOL,
       D.RIND
```

When I modification this SQL I don't get this message.

```
SELECT 
         D.UNIT_CODE,
       CASE 
         
              WHEN D.CAPITOL = 416 THEN 'CAP1'
              WHEN D.CAPITOL = 417 THEN 'CAP2'
              WHEN D.CAPITOL = 418 THEN 'Informativ'
              WHEN D.CAPITOL = 419 THEN 'Cap. SR'
         END 
          AS CAPITOL,
         D.RIND,
        TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL1))) AS COL1,
        TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL2))) AS COL2,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL3))) AS COL3,
        TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL4))) AS COL4,
        TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL5))) AS COL5,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL6))) AS COL6,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL7))) AS COL7,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL8))) AS COL8,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL9))) AS COL9,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL1))) AS COL10,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL11))) AS COL11,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL12))) AS COL12,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL13))) AS COL13,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL14)))  AS COL14,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL15))) AS COL15,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL16))) AS COL16,
      
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL17))) AS COL17,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL18))) AS COL18,
         TO_NUMBER(NVAL(MAX(D.COL19))) AS COL19
       
        
        
FROM
  VW_DATA_ALL_GC  D
  
  
  
WHERE
  (D.PERIOADA IN (:pPERIOADA))  AND   
  (D.FORM =:pFORM) AND
  (D.FORM_VERS =:pFORM_VERS) AND 
  (:pID_MDTABLE =:pID_MDTABLE) AND 
  (D.CUATM_FULL LIKE '%'||:pCOD_CUATM||';%') AND
  D.FORM IN (58)  AND
  D.CAPITOL IN (419,416,417,418)
  
 
  
  
  
  
  GROUP BY 
   D.UNIT_CODE,
   D.CAPITOL,
   D.RIND

    ORDER BY 
   D.CAPITOL,
   D.RIND
```

How find invalid number and where it apper.
When i run this SELECT = [Error] Execution  ORA-01722: invalid number

How i can find where -  invalid number = row and column.

Help  me please , how I can fiind  invalid number = row and column.

Comment: I need to get the fields where the wrong values were entered.

Comment: Without additional information, it's impossible to say. Please add at least the DDL statement for your table / view - I'd guess that at least one of the columns you're trying to aggregate is of type string (VARCHAR2 or similar).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing one of the fields your aggregating (e.g. D.COL1) has NULL values (edit: or a string or other garbage) and SUM is dying on it. If that's the case, you should be able to track down the rows with bad data pretty easily in a separate query.

Consider making those fields integer and NOT NULL if that makes sense for your data.

Comment: Oracle can't sum nulls? :o

Comment: SUM can handle NULL values perfectly fine.